# Rabbit MQ deliver manual ack

Tags: rabbitmq

I have created a sample producer and consumer in python.

Consumer receives the message and waits for 40 seconds and then gives ACK.

But in the rabbitmq UI, message rates, there is a field called Deliver (Manual Ack), I am unable to understand it.

---

Orange color - Publish (Message sent by producer)

**Blue color - Deliver (Manual Ack) - Unable to understand this field.**

Green color - Consumer ack (Happened after 40 seconds)

---

[image]